# Unzip split zip files

Tags: node.js, zip, unzip

Is there any node library which able to unzip split zip files? Or any other way? I have tried a lot of node libraries but no luck.

I am receiving files like below.

```
test.z01
test.z02
test.zip
```

I need to extract these files.

Comment: Can I ask you about the file size of each file?

Comment: File sizes are around 3mb each